# Docker rolling updates on a single node

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, rolling-updates

So I have been using `docker` with `docker-compose` for quite some time in a development environment, I love how easy it is.

Until now, I also used `docker-compose` to serve my apps on my own server as I could afford short down times like `docker-compose restart`.

But in my current project, we need rolling updates.

We still have one node, and it shall remain as we don't plan on having scalability issue for quite some time.

I read I need to use `docker swarm`, fine, but when I look for some tutorials on how to set it up, along with using my `docker-compose.yml` files, I can't find any developer-oriented (instead of devops) resources that would simply tell me the steps to achieve this, even though I don't understand everything it is ok, as I will along the way.

Are there any tutorials to learn how to set this up out there? If not, shouldn't we build it here?

I am definitely sure we are quite numerous to have the issue, as docker is now a must have for devs, but we (devs) still don't want to dive too deep into the devops world.

Cheers, hope it gets attention instead of criticism.

Comment: Do you want to run your docker-compose file in a swarm cluster?

Comment: Sure I do! I have read about the `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stackdemo` but I still need to pre-build the image hence it is unclear what do I need to set at build time or at runtime (`EXPOSE`, `ENV`, etc.). Some clarifications would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving multiple tries to `docker swarm`, I did struggle a lot with concurrency and orchestration issues, hence I decided to stick with `docker-compose` which I'm much more comfortable with.

Here's how I achieved rolling updates: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1786#issuecomment-579794865

It works actually pretty nice though observers told me it was a similar strategy to what swarm does by default.

So I guess most of my issues went away by removing replication of nodes.

When I get time, I'll give swarm another try. For now, `compose` does a great job for me.